# How can I use "a" with "or"

Tags: grammaticality, indefinite-articles, parallelism

I want to use *a* with *or*. Which of these two sentences is the correct one?

> - Do you want a full time or half time?
> - Do you want a full time or a half time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both sentences are wrong because full-time is an adjective. It is like saying "Do you want a pretty or an ugly?"

By adding a noun you correct them:

Do you want a full-time or a half-time course load?

Do you want a full-time or half-time course load?

The article "a" does not have to be repeated.

Comment: Yes, but not entirely. *"I'd like a cup of coffee, please."* *"Certainly sir. Do you want strong or weak?"* is a perfectly normal exchange. The problem with OP's sentences could just as easily be resolved by removing ***both*** articles.

Comment: @FumbleFingers but without any context; "Do you want strong or weak/bitter or sweet/rare or well-done/temporary or permanent" etc. They become difficult to decipher; likewise part-time and full-time might refer to a college course, a job, a personal trainer *almost* anything.

Comment: @FumbleFingers by the way, is "half-time job" an acceptable expression as in snailboat's answer?

Comment: @Mari-LouA *Part-time* is more usual.

Answer (score 4):

Pretend for a moment that you're starting with two questions:

> Do you want a full time?
>   Do you want a half time?

And you're combining those sentences with *or*:

> Do you want a full time or do you want a half time?

But you're repeating a lot of words there.  You decide to start removing some of the repeated stuff:

> Do you want a full time or do you want a half time?
>   Do you want a full time or <strike>do you</strike> want a half time?
>   Do you want a full time or <strike>do you want</strike> a half time? *(your first version)*
>   Do you want a full time or <strike>do you want a</strike> half time? *(your second version)*
>   Do you want a full <strike>time</strike> or <strike>do you want a</strike> half time?

You can choose how much you want to remove.  Both of your versions are fine.

It's true that *full time* and *half time* usually modify overt nouns like *position* or *job*, but it doesn't change the answer very much:

> Do you want a full-time job or do you want a half-time job?
>   Do you want a full-time job or <strike>do you</strike> want a half-time job?
>   Do you want a full-time job or <strike>do you want</strike> a half-time job?
>   Do you want a full-time job or <strike>do you want a</strike> half-time job?
>   Do you want a full-time <strike>job</strike> or <strike>do you want a</strike> half-time job?
>   Do you want a full-<strike>time job</strike> or <strike>do you want a</strike> half-time job?

Again, you can choose how much to remove, as long as it still makes sense.  It's up to you.

Comment: With that logic then I could say: "Full or half-time job? And further on, "Full or half?" which would still make sense but its meaning would be totally changed.

Comment: @Mari-LouA As long as it still makes sense **with the intended meaning**.  I thought that was clear from context, but if not, hopefully it's clear now that I've left this comment.

Comment: In writing I'd make it something like “Full- or half-time?” – you normally keep the hyphen when you elide part of a compound like that. I find it perfectly clear.